# $f$ bounded and satisfy $f(x+a+b)+f(x)=f(x+a)+f(x+b)$ implies $f$ is periodic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

Assume $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, satisfy:$$f(x+a+b)+f(x)=f(x+a)+f(x+b)$$, can we show that $f(x)$ is a periodic function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a = 1,b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ this is not true, set $f(x) = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{a}(x))+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{b}(x))$ then

$$f(x+a+b)+f(x) =\cos(\frac{2\pi}{a}(x+b))+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{b}(x+a))+ \cos(\frac{2\pi}{a}(x))+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{b}(x))$$

and

$$f(x+a)+f(x+b) = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{a}(x))+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{b}(x+a))+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{a}(x+b))+\cos(\frac{2\pi}{b}(x)).$$

So the above two quantites are equal. Suppose there is some $v > 0$ so that $f(x+v) = f(x)$ then $f(v) = f(0) = 2$ but

$$f(v) = \cos(2\pi (v))+\cos(2\pi \sqrt{2}(v)) = 2 \text{ iff } v, \sqrt{2}v \in \mathbb{Z}$$

but if $v \in \mathbb{Z}, \sqrt{2}v \notin \mathbb{Z}$ as $v > 0$; this is a contradiction.